# plot line over heatmap

Tags: python, plotly-python

hello im trying to make a heatmap with btc asks and bids, this graph will have a line representing the close price. im using :

plotly.expres as px
plotly.graph_objects as go

the code is :

```
go.Figure(go.Heatmap(x=df3["timestamp"], y=df2["asks"], z=df["baseVolume"])
px.line(df3, x="timestamp", y="close") ## not working 
fig.show()
```

[graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5tIl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since no data is presented, I have used the heatmap in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/#heatmap-with-datetime-axis) as an example for my code. Since the heatmap seems to deal with categorical variables, we need to add two axes for the y-axis, so we add a subplot. If we set the line chart to the added second axis, the heatmap and the line chart will be superimposed.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import datetime
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

programmers = ['Alex','Nicole','Sara','Etienne','Chelsea','Jody','Marianne']

base = datetime.datetime.today()
dates = base - np.arange(180) * datetime.timedelta(days=1)
z = np.random.poisson(size=(len(programmers), len(dates)))

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
        z=z,
        x=dates,
        y=programmers,
        colorscale='Viridis'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    mode='lines', 
    x=dates, 
    y=np.linspace(0,5, len(dates)).cumsum(),
    line=dict(color='red',width=2)), secondary_y=True,)
              
fig.update_layout(
    title='GitHub commits per day',
    xaxis_nticks=36)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks i manage to change some lines to adapt it to my dataframe and works, thanks again